# MODX: Show "read more" just when the content is longer than ellipsis=`400` (for example)

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I have tried coding a Modx Blog, and everything is working fine, but I want to display a "read more" button only if the content is longer than the ellipsis. The Problem is: The Content is mixed, so there are a few short announcements of about 200 signs, and then some with over 1000.

The "read more" button is now always shown, but I just want it for the "longer" blog posts. Can anyone help out?

The current code:

```
<p>[[+content:ellipsis=`300`]] <a href="[[+id]]">read more</a></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the 'length' and 'greater than' output filters for this:

```
[[+content:ellipsis=`300`]] [[+content:len:gt=`300`:then=`read more`]]
```

(Note: SO is stripping out the anchor tag above, but you get the idea)

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks! Now it works perfectly ;) Sadly I can't vote you up yet, because of reputation